# How to add test result from unittest to testrail?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, appium-ios, testrail

I have some tests with python+unittest+appium that test ios. How can I add their results to the testrail without describing how to add a result in each test?

example:

```
    def test_a(self):
        """test A"""
        if self.assertNotEqual(1, 1):
            api.results.add_result_for_case(run_id=self.id_test_run, case_id=123, status_id=1)
        else:
            api.results.add_result_for_case(run_id=self.id_test_run, case_id=123, status_id=5)
```

Comment: You might want to check out Railflow (https://railflow.io) - the platform for integrating various frameworks with TestRail. P.S. this is a commercial software with some free options and I'm developing it

Answer (score 0):

Achieving this goal is most effectively done through the utilization of the TestRail CLI. The TestRail CLI serves as a command line interface tool, enabling the seamless uploading of test automation results from any JUnit-style XML file to TestRail.

By following a code-first approach, you can upload the test results based on your specified inputs. This process creates a new test run within the designated project of your choice on TestRail.

For additional information, please refer to the official documentation of the TestRail CLI by visiting the following link:
https://support.testrail.com/hc/en-us/articles/12609674354068-Automation-workflows-Code-first